# How can I add multiple prebuilt files to system.img in Android?

Tags: android

My build system is Android 6.0. I'm building AOSP from source. I would like to include multiple prebuilt files in the generated system.img.
I know I can copy prebuilt files by using PRODUCT_COPY_FILES in device.mk. However, because some reasons, I cannot modify the system file.
How can I do it in Android.mk?

For example, I would like to copy test1.txt and test2.txt to /system/etc. I write an Android.mk such as below.

```
SMB_CONFIG_FILES := test1.txt test2.txt
SMB_CONFIG_TARGET := $(addprefix $(TARGET_OUT)/etc/, $(SMB_CONFIG_FILES))

ALL_PREBUILT += $(SMB_CONFIG_TARGET)                    
$(SMB_CONFIG_TARGET) : $(TARGET_OUT)/etc/% : $(LOCAL_PATH)/% | $(ACP)
    $(transform-prebuilt-to-target)
```

then I run 'make' to build whole source but it shows

```
build/core/main.mk:517: *** Some files have been added to ALL_PREBUILT.
build/core/main.mk:518: *
build/core/main.mk:519: * ALL_PREBUILT is a deprecated mechanism that
build/core/main.mk:520: * should not be used for new files.
build/core/main.mk:521: * As an alternative, use PRODUCT_COPY_FILES in
build/core/main.mk:522: * the appropriate product definition.
build/core/main.mk:523: * build/target/product/core.mk is the product
build/core/main.mk:524: * definition used in all products.
build/core/main.mk:525: *
build/core/main.mk:526: * unexpected test1.txt in ALL_PREBUILT
build/core/main.mk:526: * unexpected test2.txt in ALL_PREBUILT
build/core/main.mk:527: *
build/core/main.mk:528: *** ALL_PREBUILT contains unexpected files.  Stop.
```

It seems like I cannot use ALL_PREBUILT in Android 6.0.
How can I solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message details, add PRODUCT_COPY_FILES in *build/target/product/core.mk*.

Add the following lines to the *build/target/product/core.mk* file and replace `<dir>` below with the relative directory from `$ANDROID_BUILD_TOP`, the root of your AOSP directory, to the test1.txt and test2.txt files:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILE += \
    <dir>/test1.txt:system/etc/test1.txt \
    <dir>/test2.txt:system/etc/test2.txt
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. As I describe in my question, I know I can copy files by using PRODUCT_COPY_FILE added in device.mk of target product. But, some permission reasons, I cannot change the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += <my_files>` in your device configuration (`device/<vendor>/<device_name>`). The relevant files where you can add these are e.g. `device.mk`, `device-common.mk` or `<device_name>.mk`.

Another way is to use the `BUILD_PREBUILT` rule in an `Android.mk`. Here an example how such a file could look like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(my-dir)

########################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := platform.xml

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := ETC

# This will install the file in /system/etc/permissions
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_ETC)/permissions

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Of course, if you have multiple files to copy, you can just generated multiple prebuilts within a for-loop. E.g. put the above code in a separate makefile, replacing `platform.xml` with `$(MY_MODULE)` and add a for-loop to your `Android.mk` where you set `MY_MODULE := <my_module>` and `include <my_separate_makefile>`.

But this looks for me like a workaround. I would recommend using `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += <my_files>` within you product configuration.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the looping multiple modules?